# Crontab não executa script

Tags: linux, shell, centos, cron

Estou tentando executar um script pelo crontab do centos, estou fazendo assim:

```
crontab -e
```

em seguida coloquei:

```
*/1 * * * * root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh
```

obs: Antes de fazer isso, add permissões ao arquivo

```
chmod +x open.sh
```

estou correto, onde estou errando?

**Log apresentado:**

```
Jul 10 15:31:01 vps CROND[13891]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 10 15:32:01 vps CROND[14002]: (root) CMD (root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh)
Jul 10 15:32:01 vps CROND[14003]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 10 15:33:01 vps CROND[14077]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 10 15:33:01 vps CROND[14076]: (root) CMD (root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh)
Jul 10 15:34:01 vps CROND[14151]: (root) CMD (root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh)
Jul 10 15:34:01 vps CROND[14152]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 10 15:35:01 vps CROND[14263]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/dcpumon-wrapper >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 10 15:35:01 vps CROND[14266]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/test -x /usr/local/cpanel/bin/tail-check && /usr/local/cpanel/bin/tail-check)
Jul 10 15:35:01 vps CROND[14265]: (root) CMD (root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh)
Jul 10 15:35:01 vps CROND[14269]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 10 15:36:02 vps CROND[14404]: (root) CMD (root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh)
Jul 10 15:36:02 vps CROND[14405]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 10 15:37:01 vps CROND[14596]: (root) CMD (root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh)
Jul 10 15:37:01 vps CROND[14597]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 10 15:38:01 vps CROND[14647]: (root) CMD (root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh)
Jul 10 15:38:01 vps CROND[14648]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 10 15:39:01 vps CROND[14720]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/clean_user_php_sessions > /dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 10 15:39:01 vps CROND[14721]: (root) CMD (root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh)
Jul 10 15:39:01 vps CROND[14723]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 10 15:40:01 vps CROND[14812]: (root) CMD (root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh)
Jul 10 15:40:01 vps CROND[14811]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/dcpumon-wrapper >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 10 15:40:01 vps CROND[14813]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 10 15:41:01 vps CROND[14884]: (root) CMD (root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh)
Jul 10 15:41:01 vps CROND[14886]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 10 15:42:01 vps CROND[15007]: (root) CMD (root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh)
Jul 10 15:42:01 vps CROND[15008]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 10 15:43:01 vps CROND[15114]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 10 15:43:01 vps CROND[15116]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/bin/dnsqueue > /dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 10 15:43:01 vps CROND[15115]: (root) CMD (root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh)
Jul 10 15:44:01 vps CROND[15178]: (root) CMD (root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh)
Jul 10 15:44:01 vps CROND[15179]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 10 15:45:01 vps CROND[15248]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 10 15:45:01 vps CROND[15249]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/dcpumon-wrapper >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 10 15:45:01 vps CROND[15250]: (root) CMD (root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh)
Jul 10 15:46:01 vps CROND[15372]: (root) CMD (root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh)
Jul 10 15:46:01 vps CROND[15373]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 10 15:47:01 vps CROND[15547]: (root) CMD (root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh)
Jul 10 15:47:01 vps CROND[15549]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 10 15:48:01 vps CROND[15666]: (root) CMD (root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh)
Jul 10 15:48:01 vps CROND[15667]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 10 15:49:01 vps CROND[15786]: (root) CMD (root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh)
Jul 10 15:49:01 vps CROND[15787]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 10 15:50:01 vps CROND[15928]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/dcpumon-wrapper >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 10 15:50:01 vps CROND[15930]: (root) CMD (root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh)
Jul 10 15:50:01 vps CROND[15931]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 10 15:51:01 vps CROND[16090]: (root) CMD (root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh)
Jul 10 15:51:01 vps CROND[16091]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 10 15:52:01 vps CROND[16295]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 10 15:52:01 vps CROND[16296]: (root) CMD (root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh)
Jul 10 15:53:01 vps CROND[16454]: (root) CMD (root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh)
Jul 10 15:53:01 vps CROND[16455]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 10 15:54:01 vps CROND[16587]: (root) CMD (root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh)
Jul 10 15:54:01 vps CROND[16589]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
```

O script ta programado pra rodar o seguinte:

```
teste=`ps aux | grep web_socket | grep -v grep`;

# Testando se o IM gaim está rodando
if [ "$teste" ];
then
    echo "Socket ON"
else
    echo "Socket OFF"
    killall php -q web_socket2.php
    php -q web_socket2.php &
fi
```

Resumidamente é um verificador para ver se o serviço socket está ativo, se não estiver deve encerrar os vestígios do serviço e ativa-lo

Comment: Confere o log do cron com o comando " tail -fn 50 /var/log/cron ". E verifique o que está dizendo por lá! Outra coisa para que  esse " root " antes do caminho do executável ?

Comment: dentro do caminho não existe log do cron, isso é normal?

Comment: Na distro centos não! Geralmente o log fica em var/log arquivo cron! Estranho não possuir, pode ser possivel que a pessoa que configurou o serviço de cron tenha suprimido o log.

Comment: Tente executar o script direto na linha de comando.Roda?

Comment: Vamos lá, não estava mostrando o log pq tinha deslogado do ssh e eu n tinha percebido kkkk, foi mal. Ok, primeiro: eu to usando o root na frente pq vi na web que era pra usar root, mas não sei se é necessário. Segundo: o log que apareceu pra mim é *vou colocar no post*

Comment: O cron está executando a rotina como pode ver no log. O que esse script deveria fazer que não faz? Já experimentou rodar ele direto dentro do bash ?

Comment: Você pode jogar o erro do script para dentro de um arquivo assim : 

*/1 * * * * root /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/open.sh > /home/websites/public_html/erro.txt

Comment: Entendi, eu vou colocar o txt e assim que gerar mostro pra você, sobre o que esse script deveria fazer vou postar no post pra vc verificar.

Comment: Quando eu executo o comando na mão ele roda normalmente

Comment: rode também em bash php -q web_socket2.php, deve ser algo dentro dele. Se possível poste o conteúdo dele para eu ver!

Comment: Rapaz, você é um gênio kkkk. Exageros a parte você me fez raciocinar um pouco mais aqui, como você consegue ver acima, eu estava chamando as informações de forma genérica, e agora eu chamei o caminho literal e funcionou, enfim, obrigado cara, ajudou mesmo aqui. Vou postar minha solução.

Comment: Não exagere! Eu já ia postar novamente um observação, feliz por te resolvido! =P

Comment: Vlw cara, só preciso setar agora como resolvido, faz assim por favor, eu respondi ali abaixo, copia e cola em outra resposta pra eu traçar como resolvido e lhe pontuar por favor. Vlw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Concluí a questão da seguinte forma:**

```
teste=`ps aux | grep web_socket | grep -v grep`;

if [ "$teste" ];
then
    echo "Socket ON"
else
    echo "Socket OFF"
    killall /usr/local/bin/php /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/web_socket2.php
    sleep 3; /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/websites/public_html/admin/functions/web_socket2.php &
fi
```

ou seja, eu estava utilizando um caminho genérico, só precisei adicionar o caminho literal.

Comment: pontuado como correto! Não preciso desses pontos tá tranquilo rei, já fiquei feliz!

Comment: Opa, tranquilo to usando mais a comunidade agora e ta fazendo muito a diferença!! vlw!